# Spring Boot 3: How to export Logs using OTLP?

Tags: open-telemetry

I recently tried out Spring Boot 3's new observability features and were particularly interested in exposure of data using OpenTelemetry's OTLP.
I created a setup in which two Spring Boot 3 applications communicate and call each other, thus generating metrics, traces and logs.

I was successful in exposing metrics and trace spans using OTLP via micrometer, as described by the [Observability with Spring Boot 3 Blog](https://spring.io/blog/2022/10/12/observability-with-spring-boot-3).

OTLP export of Logs, however, is not described in the blog. After doing some research I did not really find any information on how to achieve that in Spring Boot 3.

I therefore looked up the OpenTelemetry Java Instrumentation's Logback appender, that potentially, should enable OTLP export of logs. However, the code is not ideal and caused lifecycle issues for me.

I have now coded my own Logback Appender - inspired by and reusing OTEL code - but I was wondering if there is a better way to do that.

### References

- My project is available [here](https://github.com/FWinkler79/spring3-observability/tree/main)
- Custom Appender is [here](https://github.com/FWinkler79/spring3-observability/blob/main/spring3-demo-client/src/main/java/com/acme/observability/demo/client/LogbackOpenTelemetryAppender.java).

Comment: can you raise an issue in https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/issues about the lifecycle issue(s) you had, so we can try to get that resolved?

Comment: Done. You can find it here: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/issues/9322